# Changing CIFS permissions on FreeNAS?

Tags: permissions, windows, cifs, freenas

I'm trying to change some permissions on a folder. I'm running FreeNAS and using the windows permissions settings (not Unix). If I right click the file and go to properties and then security, it shows that the only person who can make changes is the: root(Unix user\root).

**NOTE:** For obvious reasons I can't login to the windows share using the root user.

So how would I go about changing the settings to allow my account to change the permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For NTFS

In researching this I found this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition). According to this thread there are several ways to go about this.

#### Methods

1. Control the permissions at mount time.

   ```
   $ sudo mount -t ntfs -o \
       rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever
   ```
2. Using a user mapping file

   > Contrary to what most people believe, NTFS is a POSIX-compatible¹ filesystem, and it is possible to use permissions on NTFS.

   Consult the [ntfs-3g man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html#contenttoc) as well as this ntfs-3g documentation on [advanced ownership and permissions](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/). The user mappings is covered in this topic titled: [User Mapping](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/user-mapping/).

   You can then generate a usermap file like so:

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

#### For CIFS

In your case you're dealing with CIFS (shares mounted via `mount.cifs`) so the above would not be applicable. In that case you can use the command-line tools [getcifsacl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/getcifsacl.8.html) & [setcifsacl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/setcifsacl.8.html). The man page for `setcifsacl` has the following examples:

*Add an ACE*

```
   $ setcifsacl -a "ACL:CIFSTESTDOM\user2:DENIED/0x1/D" <file_name>
   $ setcifsacl -a "ACL:CIFSTESTDOM\user1:ALLOWED/OI|CI|NI/D" <file_name>
```

*Delete an ACE*

```
   $ setcifsacl -D "ACL:S-1-1-0:0x1/OI/0x1201ff" <file_name>
```

*Modify an ACE*

```
   $ setcifsacl -M "ACL:CIFSTESTDOM\user1:ALLOWED/0x1f/CHANGE" <file_name>
```

*Set an ACL*

```
   $ setcifsacl -S "ACL:CIFSTESTDOM\Administrator:0x0/0x0/FULL,
   ACL:CIFSTESTDOM\user2:0x0/0x0/FULL," <file_name>
```